# Wrap content by an element that satisfies a condition in Twig

Tags: twig

I often have similar boilerplate code in Twig:

```
{% if (somelongcond) %}
<div>
{% endif %}
    <p>Some long content</p>
{% if (somelongcond) %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

The problem with the above is if the condition is changed, it can be a maintenance nightmare,  I also have to go look all the way down to find the matching if statement and see if the condition is the same.

An alternative is something like this:

```
{% if (somelongcond) %}
  <div>
      {% include 'content' %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
{% include 'content' %}
```

But that requires creating a new file, which can become a mess if I need to do this many times.

Is there a better way to do the above.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good example here: https://gist.github.com/jakedohm/39190ec533e69e83b9cee4bdf3898a60

**Result:**

```
{% set content %}
  <p>Some long content</p>
{% endset %}

{% if somelongcond %}
  <div>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
{% else %}
  {{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit shorter

```
{{ if somelongcond ? '<div>'|raw }}
    <p>Some long content</p>
{{ if somelongcond ? '</div>'|raw }}
```

Then, if the same condition is repeated, you can maybe set it at the top of your file, then if you need to change it you only have to do it once.

```
{% if somelongcond %}
    {% set cond = true %}
{% else %}
    {% set cond = false %}
{% endif %}

{{ if cond ? '<div>'|raw }}
    <p>Some long content</p>
{{ if cond ? '</div>'|raw }}
```

Comment: This syntax doesn't work for me. I think the 'if' statement can't be in double brackets.